# NodeJs : Image comparision

Tags: java, .net, node.js, image, comparison

I have nodejs application where I need to compare an image to the rest of the images in the folder to find the best match. Is there any module to do this?? I don't mind using .net/java if they powerful enough for my requirement. 
Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

For a comparison of the two images you need Java (.net,C, etc) application based on neural networ, k to implement it on node.js very hard. Let's assume we have a java app for comparison, you need to run it through exec() in node.js. For example:

```
 var exec   = require('child_process').exec;

exec("/usr/bin/java -jar comparision.jar --images *path to images folder*", function (error, stdout) {
    //and here we get match image path in stdout
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Siavolt. I am actually looking for a framework/jar to do comparison. You actually told me how to execute a jar in nodejs.